# enable button if user fill the input box, if user emptied or not fill then disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable the button once user fill or type something on the input box and disabled it if user not fill or emptied the input box. Sadly, my snippet below is not working. Any help, suggestion, recommendation, ideas and clues is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keypress(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
      //user fill or did type something on the input search box, lets enable the button
      $("button").attr("disabled", false);
    }else if($(this).val() === ""){
      //user not fill or emptied the box, lets disabled the button
      $("button").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Type your search here" />
<button disabled>Go</button>
```

Comment: you're missing closing curly braces for else if condition.. is that a typo..?

Comment: @CodeDemon your `ifelse` did't not closed well.

Comment: What is expected result if `input` value is multiple space characters ?

Comment: solved, thanks to @Brino! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you missing braces. Working now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        //user fill or did type something on the input search box, lets enable the button
        $("button").prop("disabled", false);
      } else if ($(this).val() === "") {
        //user not fill or emptied the box, lets disabled the button
        $("button").prop("disabled", true);

      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Type your search here" />
<button disabled>Go</button>
```

Comment: yeah, however, I want to disable back the button if user emptied or not fill the input box

Comment: @CodeDemon code updated. Seem like you problem solved. Glad to hear that. CHeers!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the disabled attribute to true / false using the `prop()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
      $("button").prop('disabled',$(this).val().length <= 0 );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Type your search here" />
<button disabled>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `input` , `focus` events , for `input` being focused while `input` `.length` not greater than `0` .

Note, Not certain about expected result if `input` value multiple space characters ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("input focus", function(){
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      //user fill or did type something on the input search box, lets enable the button
      $("button").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      //user not fill or emptied the box, lets disabled the button
      $("button").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Type your search here" />
<button disabled>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length > 0){
          $("button").attr("disabled", false);
      }
      else {
          $("button").attr("disabled", true);
      }
  });
});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/nhf52ceh/